# Double border makes the div larger

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I'm using React and Tailwind, I want to achieve this :

[image: Goal input]

So I added a border on both button + and -, and I added a border on the parent div to display a border on all the element.

Problem is, the borders on buttons seemes to be larger because of the 2 borders.

If I use a border only on the right for - button, we can see it misses a little pixels with no border...

How can I achieve it ?

Here is a [Tailwind Playground](https://play.tailwindcss.com/YqssWz8rbX)

Here is my code :

```
<div class="p-8">
  <div class="flex w-fit items-center rounded ring-1 ring-neutral-300">
    <button type="button" class="h-10 w-10 rounded border border-neutral-300 bg-transparent focus:outline-none">-</button>

    <input id="{id}" type="number" value="{count}" class="arrow-hide h-10 w-16 rounded border-none text-center text-base font-semibold focus:outline-none" />

    <button type="button" class="h-10 w-10 rounded border border-neutral-300 bg-transparent focus:outline-none">+</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I use a border only on the right for - button, we can see it misses a little pixels with no border...

Actually it is not missing any pixels , it seems to be faded because of the rounded border.

---

**Feasible solution:**

1. Remove `rounded` from the `+` and `-` divs
2. Apply only left and right border to the respective divs.

**Updated Code:**

```
<div class="p-8">
  <div class="flex w-fit items-center rounded ring-1 ring-neutral-300">
    <button type="button" class="h-10 w-10 border-r border-neutral-300 bg-transparent focus:outline-none">-</button>

    <input id="{id}" type="number" value="{count}" class="arrow-hide h-10 w-16 rounded border-none text-center text-base font-semibold focus:outline-none" />

    <button type="button" class="h-10 w-10 border-l border-neutral-300 bg-transparent focus:outline-none">+</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Output:**

[image]

[Tailwind-play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/2WaONsAGXH)

Comment: Thank you very much. It is not 100% like the image but I can manage the rounded on corners. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Since you want a rounded border on the inside corner of the buttons as well, IMHO the best solution is to make them overlap the border of the container:

```
margin: -1px; position: relative; z-index: 1; height: calc(2.5rem + 2px);
```

They need two extra pixels of height, so that will probably have to be hard-coded like this, don't see any way to directly combine this with the `h-10` class here. z-index is needed so that the input field will not be on top of the left button's right-side border.

And of course it will only work if you don't need any alpha transparence on those borders.