# How to make 2 borders overlap?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I use tailwind and i need to achieve this :
[image]

So I made a border on the parent element and on both buttons (increment and decrement).

Problem : when there are 2 borders, we can see it. And the render is not like my template :
[image]

I added class `-m-px` but not sufficient.

Here is the [playground](https://play.tailwindcss.com/cBRD5N08n6)

Here is the code :

```
<div class="flex flex-col gap-2 p-8">
  <div class="flex w-fit items-center rounded border border-solid border-neutral-300">
    <button type="button" class="-m-px mr-0 h-10 w-10 rounded border border-solid border-neutral-300 bg-transparent hover:cursor-pointer focus:outline-none">
      -
    </button>

    <input id="{id}" type="number" value="0" class="h-10 w-16 rounded border-none text-center text-base font-semibold focus:outline-none" />

    <button type="button" class="-m-px ml-0 h-10 w-10 rounded border border-solid border-neutral-300 bg-transparent hover:cursor-pointer focus:outline-none">
      +
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Double border makes the div larger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75884948/double-border-makes-the-div-larger)

Comment: no, because the render is not exaclty the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider using arbitary value if you want to have 1px in only one side of the div

[image]

```
<div class="flex flex-col gap-2 p-8">
  <div class="flex w-fit items-center rounded border border-solid border-neutral-300">
    <button type="button" class="mr-0 h-10 w-10 rounded border-r-[1px] border-solid border-neutral-300 bg-transparent hover:cursor-pointer focus:outline-none">-</button>

    <input id="{id}" type="number" value="0" class="h-10 w-16 rounded border-none text-center text-base font-semibold focus:outline-none" />

    <button type="button" class="h-10 w-10 rounded border-l-[1px] border-solid border-neutral-300 bg-transparent hover:cursor-pointer focus:outline-none">+</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**Edit:**

Zero is placed slightly left because of the up and down arrows which will let the user to increment/decrement the value.

[image]

To remove this you need to add following code in the `css` file

```
@layer components {
  input[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
  input[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0;
  }
}
```

**Final Output:**

[image]

[Tailwind-css](https://play.tailwindcss.com/NrICYGCCqh?file=css)

Comment: You can see there is some "missing" pixels. I need a 100% match

Comment: Can you point me exactly and explain me clearly what you mean be "missing pixels"

Comment: You are pointing me the position of 0 is not exactly to the center ? is it the problem

Comment: if you are talking about the horizontal alignment of `-` `0` and `+` , there are properly placed where there supposed to be , in a straight line.

Comment: @Johan The input looks uncentered due to the up/down arrows in some browsers for `<input type="number">`. If you use `<input type="text">` it will look centered.

Comment: @qrsngky, thank you for pointing me the exact issue. I have taken care of the issue. hope it would help the answer seeker.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `style=border-(left/right): 1px solid #ccc;` to the button style.

style="border-right: 1px solid #ccc;

```
<div class="flex flex-col gap-2 p-8">
  <div class="flex w-fit items-center rounded border border-solid border-neutral-300">
    <button type="button" class="-m-px mr-0 h-10 w-10 rounded border border-solid border-neutral-300 bg-transparent hover:cursor-pointer focus:outline-none style="border-right: 1px solid #ccc;">
      -
    </button>
    <input id="{id}" type="number" value="0" class="h-10 w-16 rounded border-none text-center text-base font-semibold focus:outline-none" />

    <button type="button" class="-m-px ml-0 h-10 w-10 rounded border border-solid border-neutral-300 bg-transparent hover:cursor-pointer focus:outline-none style="border-left: 1px solid #ccc;">
      +
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```